# how does psr-0 and composer work?

Tags: symfony, composer-php, autoload, psr-0

I'll ask the question with an example.
Say I have a project directory like so.

```
project

  vendor

      samplevendor

  src

  composer.json
```

First i want to know if i have placed the composer.json file in the project directory correctly in order to install libraries in the vendor directory?second, say i have the following lines the composer.json

```
 "autoload":{
      "psr-0": {
              "samplevendor\\package": "lib/"
                }
            }
```

then where will composer configure autoloading to look for the class samplevendor\package\sampleclass in regards to the project root?
I ask this after having seen the following lines in the symfony2 composer.locked file:

```
 "autoload": {
            "psr-0": {
                "Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\": "lib/"
            }
        }
```

update:I found the corresponding namespace map in autoload_namespaces.php which just doesn't  seem to be in accordance with psr-0:

'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/annotations/lib')

Answer (score 2):

You probably can place the `composer.json` anywhere in your project depending on requirements, but for a pure PHP (and HTML/CSS/JS) project, it is the best idea to place the file in the topmost directory. That way Composer would be able to find it if you create a library or want some other nice side effects. (There are plenty of them that do not directly affect how Composer or your software works).

It is a good idea to create an initial `composer.json` by running `composer init`. Composer will ask you about a vendor name and software name. I recommend you give a reasonable answer here. Also, you can add yourself as a developer, add some dependencies right now (not necessarily needed), and finally create the initial file.

PSR-0 autoloading means that the given prefix of namespace or class name (remember those Underscore_Classname_Namespace_Emulation) is to be searched in the directory, i.e. a class named `\Namespace\Class` that is configured as `"psr-0": {"Namespace\\": "src"}` will be located at `src/Namespace/Class.php` (if the file is not there, maybe another component is able to load that exact class, so autoloading will not immediately fail - Composer will register that failure and see if a later autoload definition can load it).

The fact you see different definitions in the `autoload_namespaces.php` file for required libraries is correct. Composer has to load these from different directories located inside `vendor`, and your own classes will be autoloaded from the location given in your autoload section in the composer.json file.